# Android AudioTrack.write returns -4

Tags: java, android, audio

I'm playing some audio on Android using the `AudioTrack`. Sometimes I get a return value of '`-4`' from the write method. 
The documentation say it will return

> the number of shorts that were written or ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION if
>   the object wasn't properly initialized, or ERROR_BAD_VALUE if the
>   parameters don't resolve to valid data and indexes.

The values of "ERROR" constants in AudioTrack is:

- ERROR = -1
- ERROR_BAD_VALUE = -2
- ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION = -3

So what does -4 mean?

Here is the code...roughly

```
int bufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioEncoding);
audioTrack = new AudioTrack(streamType, sampleRate, channelConfig, audioEncoding, bufferSize, audioMode);
if(audioTrack.getState() != AudioTrack.STATE_UNINITIALIZED){
    audioTrack.play();
    int response = audioTrack.write(data, 0, size);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native implementation of [`AudioTrack::write`](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/frameworks/av/tree/media/libmedia/AudioTrack.cpp?h=aosp-new/master#n1379) calls [`obtainBuffer`](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/frameworks/av/tree/media/libmedia/AudioTrack.cpp?h=aosp-new/master#n1304), and in case `obtainBuffer` returned an error, `write` returns that same error.

`obtainBuffer` returns `-EINTR` in case it's called when the `AudioTrack` state is `STATE_STOPPING`, and `-EINTR` happens to be `-4`, so my best guess is that you're doing a write while the track (for some reason) is stopping.

Comment: Yes, "for some reason". It looks like AudioTrack stops for some reason when I'm not expecting it. Thanks.